Disk at 50% but disk 0 is at 100% while disk 1 is 0%
Disk 0 (C:) shows 100% with spikes is average response time. While Disk 1 (D:) shows 0%, my PC used to be snappy until last week, now it struggles to run anything and usually get no response if I click on something that's loading. I reseted and wiped HDD (Disk 0) added a new windows version from a flash drive, and I still have the same issue, my HDD light stays on red and HDDScan shows the spike in processing time where it will drop to 500ms slower


Perhaps consider replacing spinning rust with a modern SSD. It will result in a tremendous performance boost for nearly everything you do on your PC.

If you mean 100% of Disk Active Time in Task Manager, then the machine is using that drive for some purpose.
To find out what process is using the drive,

Press CtrlShiftEsc to open Task Manager.
In the Details tab, add columns for I/O reads and I/O writes.



Click on the I/O reads header to sort by that column, as shown, and see what processes are performing I/O reads. In this case, it's csrss.exe and MsMpEng.exe,
Click on I/O writes header to sort by that, and see what processes are performing I/O reads.


System is running, had previously taken it off but as its a fresh reset havent as of yet, this didnt resolve my problem previously. I can get the smart, following link is the SMART https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xldPqcifVgHTOrNOhI3RlMhZmF71SRsi/view?usp=sharing
